# Change image source based on asp:DropDownList selection

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, image

I want to be able to change an image depending on what is selected in the drop down box...

I have this JS code to change the image. Simplified of course.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function changeImage()
        {
            var oDDL = document.all("ddlNAME");
            var NAME= oDDL.options[oDDL.selectedIndex].text;

            switch(NAME)
            {
                case "Name":
                    document.getElementById("img").src="img1.png";
                    break;
                case "Name2":
                    document.getElementById("img").src="img2.png";
                    break;
                default:
                    document.getElementById("img").src="img3.png";
            }
        }
    </script>
```

When I call this function I do it in my DDL implementation.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNAME" runat="server" OnTextChanged="changeImage()" >
```

But for some reason the `changeImage()` is not firing. it is giving me an error saying

```
'changeImage' is not a member of 'ASP.default_aspx'
```

I know this is a noob question and it is something small... But this is my first day every using javascript so bear with me please. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have told it to run a server-side event, so it is trying to find a function called changeImage() within your ASPX script.

You need it to run a Javascript event client-side.  Use the `onChanged()` event instead.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNAME" runat="server" onChanged="changeImage();" >
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNAME" runat="server" onchange="changeImage()" >
```

I believe the way you are using it is making it try and call a class instead of a javascript function.

Comment: Not a class, a function in the codebehind file for the ASPX page.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNAME" runat="server" onchange="changeImage();" >
```

instead of the `OnTextChanged`

Comment: onChanged is a server-side function.

Comment: Thanks @K4emic, that is what I was thinking and I have updated it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the dropdown list is being treated as a server element, rather than a client-side control.  When it is changed, your entire page is posting back to the server, which is looking for a method called `changeImage` in your page's class -- and when it does not find it, it is throwing the error.

In addition, you'll want to avoid things like `document.all`.  Use `document.getElementById` instead.  Among other things, `document.all` is an extension to DOM Level 0, and is much slower than `getElementById`.

Answer (score 1):

`OnTextChanged` is an ASP.Net event, it's not for JavaScript. It's looking in your .vb file for a VB function called `changeImage()`.

You can try using `onChange="changeImage()"`.

You can also use the `this` keyword in your function to reference the object that your function is running on (in this case the dropdown box) instead of searching for it through `getElementById()` or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change your dropdown code to this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNAME" runat="server" onchange="changeImage()" AutoPostBack="false" >
```

The onchange is a javascript event handler, the eventhandler you were using is an ASP.NET control event handler.  The AutoPostBack attribute is necessary to keep your control from causing a postback (to execute server side code) when you clearly want client code to run.

Answer (score 1):

You have to register the JavaScript code to the Page, and then change the "OnChange" attribute of the DropDownList to your JS function. You can [read more here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479011.aspx) in the "RegisterStartupScript" and "RegisterClientScriptBlock" sections.